# rar move files from subfolder to root by command

Tags: command-line, rar

i using windows and **cmd** to move some files in a **rar** directory into root of **rar** by command line?
i am using windows and **cmd** to rename files
i can rename files by **rn** and **rar** project:

```
rar rn out.rar file1.jpg file3.jpg
```

it work

but this is dont work:

```
rar rn out.rar files/finf1.jpg files/finf3.jpg
```

where is my porblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAR file format uses backslashes internally. Changing the forward slashes and it works for me:

```
rar rn out.rar files\finf1.jpg files\finf3.jpg
```